# OSX Lion terminal lost all colors

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, osx-lion

I recently upgraded to Lion only to find that Terminal.app (and iTerm2, which I actually use instead) have totally lost all colors. This means no syntax highlighting in Vim, no colored directory names or filenames, no nothing. I've tried playing around with the terminal-type option in the preferences (for both apps), changing it to `xterm-256color`, `xterm-new`, `xterm`, etc. but all to no avail.

However! When I SSH into a remote machine in Terminal.app, I get colors! Everything works as it once did. Although this isn't the same with iTerm2, where I'm still left colourless.

Comment: I've been able to get the prompt to have colors by adding code to the ~/.profile file, but I'm not sure where the code for the folders goes. I only do this once a year or so... This didn't work for me, maybe you? http://blog.toddwerth.com/entries/13

Comment: If when you state "I'm not sure where the code for the colors go" you mean LSCOLORS, then maybe you should check out http://softwaregravy.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/ls-colors-for-mac/.  I'm assuming that you mean the colors for when you perform an `ls` on a directory and you see different files and folders, and you are wanting to change the color of the folder.

Comment: I added some info to that effect supplemental to my first answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to edit ~/.profile and put this code in to make folders color.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

[This shows LSCOLORS options.](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/04/enabling-bash-terminal-directory-file-color-highlighting-mac-os-x/)

I used this to make a custom cursor:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@macair\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Hope this helps.

For vim, use a theme like [this theme](https://github.com/ikej/my-vim-profiles/blob/master/colors/ir_black.vim)

And add 2 folders, ~/.vim and ~/.vim/colors

Put the theme file in your ~/.vim/colors folder

Then make a file called ~/.vimrc with something like this:

```
syntax on        'this is needed to see syntax
set background=dark  "makes it easier to read with black background
colorscheme ir_black "set theme in ./vim/colors folder
set ls=2            " allways show status line
set hlsearch        " highlight searches
"set incsearch       " do incremental searching
set ruler           " show the cursor position all the time
set visualbell t_vb=    " turn off error beep/flash
set ignorecase        "ignore case while searching
set number            'put numbers on side
```

I've added comments so you can pick and choose what you want. Also, I ended up tweaking the theme. It made comments grey and they were too hard to read.

Comment: This partially works and does show colours when doing an `ls` for example. Still no coloring anywhere else in the shell though (e.g. in Vim)

Comment: You have to add the colors to vim the same way. I just did it. You need folder ~/.vim/colors/whatevertheme.vim and you need a ~/.vimrc file that specifies that you want to use the whatevertheme.

Comment: This doesn't work either - Vim is reading the colors file but I'm still getting a monochrome terminal. I still get full colours when SSHing into another machine though :/

Comment: Actually, after much playing around it turned out the LSCOLORS option was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need add these settings on your `.vimrc`

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
syntax on
```

To enable your color highlighting.

I was using my `.vimrc`, which does not have these, but works in Linux and old OS X versions. For Lion, you need add them.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following in my ~/.profile

```
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\*\1/'
}

case "$TERM" in
  xterm-*color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac


if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
```

Comment: This is amazing!